# How to decompile published asp.net mvc core files

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

Please, I want to decompile my asp.net mvc core files I publish to a server, I did a git fetch that and update my local repo the old commits and now I can't get my latest changes.

From the host server, I have been able to retrieve www and views folders, I want to be able to see my controllers and some other codes.

Comment: Are you trying to view the actual "decompiled" code (there are numerous utilities available for that) or trying to pull the source code from Git?  It seems like the latter based on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to decompile with ILSpy tools from [ILSpy for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.ILSpy), it saved my day.

What I have to do was to

1. Download and install the extension.
2. Open visual studio.
3. Click on tool > ILSpy.
4. Import the Dll File.
5. Right-Click on the DLL.
6. Save Code.

Here is the screenshot of ILSpy:
    [image: screenshot]